# Delete Google Drive file permenantly using DriveApp in Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

There is `removeFile` method in `DriveApp API` for Google App Script, but [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#removefilechild) it states that this method does not delete file permanently. All the files removed using this method can be found using search bar in Google Drive. Is there a way to delete file permanently from Google Drive using Google APP Script?

Comment: You need to do research before blindly asking questions

Comment: I am very sorry, I had seen this answer before but got confused in `Drive.files` and `DriveApp.files`

Comment: yes, there is the chance to be confused by the native, simpler, and less capable Apps Script implementation of `Drive`, which is accessed by `DriveApp`, and the powerful, "advanced service" `Drive`, which is an Apps Script client library that implements v2 of the Drive REST API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).setTrashed(true);
```

Comment: This will move file to trash but won't delete it permanently.

Comment: Yes, if you want to Delete it from Trash then you can use `Drive.Files.emptyTrash();`

Comment: @DarpanSanghavi and also delete every other trashed file, which may not be desired.